# Safe use of ImageMagick convert

Tags: php, security, imagemagick

I am planning on using the following to resize animated GIFs.

Would it be recommended to do other checks on the file before passing to `convert`? The filename is auto-generated in the upload script.

```
$filename = escapeshellarg($filename);
exec('convert image.gif -resize 150x400^ -gravity center -extent 150x400 ' . $filename);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should use `convert` with prepending the absolute path to the executable that you want to execute.
2. You should be sure that you can trust the `convert` command which you want to execute.
3. You should prepend the absolute path to the input file which you want to process.
4. You should check for file size, (magic) file format, pixel dimensions and layer canvas geometry of the input file you want to process. For example:

   ```
   identify                                                           \
     -format "%f : bytes=%b format=%m width=%w height=%h canvas=%g\n" \
      /path/to/input/image
   ```

   (Make yourself familiar with the meanings of `%f`, `%b`, `%m`, `%w`, `%h` and `%g` ***[here](http://imagemagick.com/script/escape.php)***.)
5. You should prepend the absolute path to the output file which you want to write.
6. You should be very sure that `$filename` is not containing unwanted characters.

Comment: Nice detail. Could you expand on the second point? Are there certain convert commands that shouldn't be run?

Answer (score 0):

if file name in not from user input (even part of it) and you generate it with random character or data like user id, and you can be absolutely sure there is no unwanted data or characters in it, there is no need to be worry.